# How to use dependency injection in .NET Standard project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-standard

Is it possible to use dependency injection in a standalone .NET Standard project without an ASP.NET Core web application project?

Since there is no `startup.cs` file, I am curious to find out if this is possible, and if it is how it can be done?

Comment: What is `standalone .net standard project`? you mean `Class Library Project` that targets `.NET Standard`?

Comment: Correct, that is it

Comment: A class library doesn't have its own dependency injection. It has constructors you wire up to the DI of the calling application. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: A class library does not and cannot run on it's own. So, where will this library be used and called from? That can probably better answer your question.

Comment: @mko: Would you (mind if I) [edit] your question to include both .NET Standard projects as well as class libraries? Obviously, .NET Standard projects _are_ class libraries, but everything in this question, as well as the answers—including mine—apply to class libraries more generally. E.g., this is all still relevant to people using .NET 6 class libraries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can do this. In fact, even if your class libraries were in the *same* assembly as an ASP.NET Core implementation, it’s preferred to make your libraries entirely unaware of both your specific dependencies and any dependency injection container you’re using.

> **TL;DR:** Both your dependencies and any dependency injection container you’re using should be configured in your *application*’s composition root (e.g., `Startup`), not in your *library*. Read on for details.

### Core Concepts

First of all, it's useful to remember that, fundamentally, dependency injection is a set of patterns and practices for achieving loosely coupled code, and *not* a specific dependency injection *container*. That's important here as you don't want your libraries to become dependent upon whatever dependency injection container you may choose to use, such as the one built-in to ASP.NET Core. The container is simply a tool that helps *automate* the construction, management, and injection of dependencies into your libraries.

Given that, your .NET Standard Class Library should be written to *allow* dependencies to be injected from whatever application it is being implemented in, while being completely agnostic to what dependencies or even container is being used. Typically that is done through *constructor injection*, in which dependencies are exposed as parameters in a class’s constructor. In that case, you just want to expose dependencies in your constructors through their abstractions—namely through an interface that describes the implementation.

These concepts are easier to understand with an example.

### Example

Let’s say you need access to some type of data persistence layer (such as a database) for users, but you don't want your class library to be tightly coupled to any single implementation (such as a SQL Server database).

#### Abstraction

In that case, you might create an `IUserRepository` abstraction, which your concrete implementations can implement. Here’s a barebones example, which exposes a single `GetUser()` method:

```cs
public interface IUserRepository 
{
    User GetUser(int userId);
}
```

#### Constructor Injection

Then, for any classes that depend on that service, you will implement a constructor which allows the `IUserRepository` abstraction to be injected into it:

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public MyClass(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));
    }
    public string GetUserName(int userId) => _userRepository.GetUser(userId).Name;
}
```

#### Concrete Implementation

Now, you can create a concrete implementation of the `IUserRepository`—let us say a `SqlUserRepository`.

```cs
public class SqlUserRepository: IUserRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public SqlUserRepository(string connectionString) 
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
    }
    public GetUser(int userId) 
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

Critically, this implementation *could* be in an entirely separate assembly; the assembly which contains `IUserRepository` and `MyClass` needn't be aware of it at all.

#### Dependency Injection

So where does the actual dependency injection happen? In whatever application that implements your .NET Standard Class Library. So, for instance, if you have an ASP.NET Core application, you might configure your dependency injection container via your `Startup` class to inject an instance of `SqlUserRepository` for any classes which depend upon an `IUserRepository`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    //Register dependencies
    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository>(c => new SqlRepository("my connection string"));
}
```

In that regard, your front-end application provides the *glue* between your .NET Standard Class Library and whatever services it depends upon.

> **Important:** This could just as easily be a console application instead. It could use a third-party dependency injection container, such as Ninject. Or you could manually wire up your dependency graph in your *composition root*. What’s important here is that your .NET Standard class library doesn’t know or care, so long as *something* gives it its dependencies.

#### Assembly References

In the above example, your assembly structure might look something like this:

- `My.Library.dll`

  - `IUserRepository`
  - `MyClass`
- `My.Library.Sql.dll` (references `My.Library.dll`)

  - `SqlUserRepository`
- `My.Web.dll` (references `My.Library.dll`,`My.Library.Sql.dll`)
- `My.Console.dll` (references `My.Library.dll`,`My.Library.Sql.dll`)

Notice that `My.Library` is completely unaware of either the concrete implementations (e.g., `My.Library.Sql.dll`) or the applications which will implement it (e.g., `My.Web.dll`, `My.Console.dll`). All it aware of is that an `IUserRepository` will be injected into `MyClass` when it is constructed.

> **Important:** These *could* all be in the same assembly. But even if they are, it’s useful to *think* of them as separate in order to maintain loose coupling between your dependency injection container, your core business logic, and your concrete implementations.

#### Best Practices

While not strictly required, a best practice is for your dependencies to be *required* parameters which are treated as *read-only* by your class. You can create a lot problems for yourself if you expose either optional dependencies, or dependencies which can be replaced during the lifetime of an object.

The above class structure demonstrates the ideal implementation by requiring the parameter:

```cs
public MyClass(IUserRepository userRepository)
```

Adding a guard clause to prevent null values:

```cs
_userRepository = userRepository?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));
```

And, finally, assigning it to a `readonly` field so it can’t be replaced with a different implementation later:

```cs
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you are writing a log reader library that fetches data from several sources:

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    Task<(IEnumerable<LogModel>, int)> FetchDataAsync(
        int page,
        int count,
        string level = null,
        string searchCriteria = null
    );
}
```

And you have multiple implementations for the above interface:

```
public class SqlServerDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly RelationalDbOptions _options;

    public SqlServerDataProvider(RelationalDbOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public async Task<(IEnumerable<LogModel>, int)> FetchDataAsync(
        int page,
        int count,
        string logLevel = null,
        string searchCriteria = null
    )
    { ... }
```

And here is `RelationalDbOptions` class

```
public class RelationalDbOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public string Schema { get; set; }
}
```

Let's create a `ServiceCollection`extension method to register dependencies:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSqlServerLogReader(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<RelationalDbOptions> options
    )
    {
        if (services == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

        if (optionsBuilder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(optionsBuilder));

        var relationalDbOptions = new RelationalDbOptions();
        options.Invoke(relationalDbOptions );
        services.AddSingleton(relationalDbOptions);

        Services.AddScoped<IDataProvider, SqlServerDataProvider>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Now if you want to use your log reader library with ASP.NET Core or Console application, you can register log reader dependencies ba calling `AddSqlServerLogReader` in `ConfigureServices` method or anywhere that you are creating `ServiceCollection`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSqlServerLogReader(options => { 
           options.ConnectionString = ""; 
           options.LogTableName = ""
    });
    ...
}
```

It's a common pattern to register library dependencies. Checkout real implementation [here](https://github.com/mo-esmp/serilog-ui).

Comment: I mentioned in my question, i dont have ASP.NET Core or Console application. it is a standalone Class Library Project

Comment: @mko: That’s not a problem. Just remember that your class library can’t run by itself. It is ultimately  going to be called from an application. That might be an ASP.NET Core web application, a .NET Console app, a Unity game, a Xamarin phone app, a WCF desktop application—or some combination of these. And when it is, it’s up to that application to construct and inject the dependencies—possibly using a dependency injection container. ASP.NET Core ships with one such container out of the box, but there are others that work in any .NET Core or .NET Framework app. Or you can wire them up manually.

Comment: @mko As a .NET developer perhaps you know that a `Class Library` does not and cannot run on its own and you have to use that library with ASP.NET Core web app, a .NET Console app, Desktop app ... as @Jeremy Caney said.

Comment: Do you place "ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs" along with the rest of your class library content and make your library dependent on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions - or - do you create a library specifically for dependency injection purposes, e.g. YourLibrary.DependencyInjection, resp. YourLibrary.Ninject, etc..?

Comment: @thomasgalliker It depends! For simplicity, I just place `ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs` along with my library and do not create an extra package for it; however, if you have multiple DI containers to integrate with, it make sensemakeshave different packages for it like `MediatR.Extensions.*`.

Comment: True. This leads to the question, how can you know what DI container the users of your library have? The same goes for the logging abstraction: How can you know if your library consumers will be using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging? You can always build your own abstractions, but this is sometimes a huge extra effort and can also lead to confusion.

Comment: I don't like to create an abstraction over abstraction especially for `ILogger`. Hence it's part of the framework, most people use `ILogger`. Still, you can add the dependencies to `IServiceCollection` and use another DI to inject dependencies and of course, in some cases like lazy injection and named instance you need to use the actual DI dependency registration.

Answer (score 1):

As we know, a Class Library cannot execute own its own. You have to reference it from a console or an ASP.NET Core project—let’s call those executables—which will then call your library.

Your Dependency Injection configurations runs before the actual code in your class library. In a library, we don't have any entry point to configure the dependency injection container; we have to make one and then call it from our executable’s `Startup` or `Main`.

For example, EF Core is just a library, but it has an *extension method* (serving as an entry point) which allows you to configure it with DI:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped) where TContext : DbContext
{
    library configurations
}
```

You can take this same approach in your code.